# WPF C# .NET Noob requesting some advice (Using Visual Studio 2012 RC)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I've been mainly working with windows forms, but would like to use WPF instead. Generally I like to manage my applications with a Manager.cs file. I will set the manager to be the entry point and it will load for example my main window.

From what I've read the Main() entry point is automatically generated when WPF is run. I've tried changing the XAML file to run my Manager.cs file, but it complains when I do so.

I'm a complete noob with WPF, anyone got any suggestions for how to keep everything encapsulated in a Manager.cs file and have that run at startup?

Comment: this already exists in WPF : app.xaml.cs file, this can be changed to manager.cs... but is it really worth it ?

Comment: @ICTech I actually find `App` more accurately conveys the "centre" of the application, and what with the explosion of much smaller applications in the form of "Apps", it makes even *more* sense. So I agree with Kek, is it really worth it?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. This is what I was after. I'll use the app.xaml.cs as my centre :) Thanks for the advice

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/03/i-shall-call-it-somethingmanager.html

Comment: I think it makes it easier to manage code having a focal point for things to run through. Hence using "Managers". Some people don't like it, but I find it tidies everything up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I advise not bothering, you should just be able to change the App.xaml file name to Manager.xaml (which in turn created Manager.xaml.cs), and then in the new Manager.xaml.cs, change `App` to `Manager` on the partial class definition.

The other half of the partial class is the auto-generated stuff.

You can then access `Manager.Current` as you would have previously done `App.Current`.